# Regex for Version Number Format

Tags: regex, groovy

Could you please help in giving me the regex for the following version number format:

e.g. 10.01.03-13

< major >.< minor >.< patch >-< buildnumb >

Comment: What have you tried so far? And what do you need to do with the regex? Extract numbers? Check format? Match something? Also you should tag programming language.

Comment: Do you always have all parts? I.e. isn't it possible that sometimes the buildnumber is missing? Also, do you want to extract the parts? Which language are you using?

Comment: I'm trying to use 

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Validating+String+Parameter+Plugin

to ensure the user always put the right version number as a parameter.  The format is always going to be 10.020.203-23... build number will always be there

Comment: `(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\-([\d]+)`

Comment: (\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\-([\d\-]+) is not good as it matches the following pattern

35.01.44-3-444-444

I just want to have the build number as the qualifier, nothing else after

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a simple match on digits following the pattern of digit-dot-digit-dot-digit-hyphen-digit, since [groovy uses the java engine](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_regular_expression_operators).

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\-(\d+)
```

#### [Test](http://myregexp.com?regex=(%5Cd%2B)%5C.(%5Cd%2B)%5C.(%5Cd%2B)%5C-(%5Cd%2B)&text=10.01.03-13)

`#1` = major

`#2` = minor

`#3` = patch

`#4` = buildnumb

Answer (score 2):

You can also use named groups if you fancy:

```
def version = '10.01.03-13'

def parser = /(?<major>\d+).(?<minor>\d+).(?<revision>\d+)-(?<build>\d+)/

def match = version =~ parser
if(match.matches()) {
    def (major, minor, revision, build) = ['major', 'minor', 'revision', 'build'].collect { match.group(it) }
}
```