# My list need to be stripped down

Tags: regex, groovy

I need to get this list (that i got in a list in groovy)

```
aaaaa_1.1.0.405.zip    
bb-1.1.0.767.zip          
xxxx.1.1.0.146.zip
yyyy.1.1.0.135.zip                     
zzzzz.1.1.0.129.zip
```

that is in a list to be writen down to 5 different variabels with only the verison number left in groovy. As you can see it will be diffrent names in front of the numbers that needs to be stripped away as well as the .zip

So the list will be like this

```
def 1 = 1.1.0.405
def 2 = 1.1.0.767
def 3 = 1.1.0.146
def 4 = 1.1.0.135
def 5 = 1.1.0.129
```

My code right now is this:

```
node {
    def list = getAllFiles(createFilePath("${workspace}"))

    for(i in 0 .. list.size()-1) {
        println list.get(i)
    }
}


@NonCPS
def getAllFiles(rootPath) {
    def list = []
    for (subPath in rootPath.list()) {
        list << subPath.getName()
        // in case you don't want extension
        // list << FilenameUtils.removeExtension(subPath.getName())
    }
    return list
}

// Helps if slave servers are in picture
def createFilePath(def path) {
    if (env['NODE_NAME'].equals("master")) {
        File localPath = new File(path)
        return new hudson.FilePath(localPath);
    } else {
        return new hudson.FilePath(Jenkins.getInstance().getComputer(env['NODE_NAME']).getChannel(), path);
    }
}
```

I have tried this code but it wont find anything:.

output:

```
aaaaa_1.1.0.405.zip
[Pipeline] echo
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+) region=0,26 lastmatch=]
[Pipeline] }
```

code:

```
 def version = list.get(0)    
 println version
 def parser = /(\d+).(\d+).(\d+).(\d+)/

 def match = version =~ parser
 println match

 if(match.matches()) {
 def test= version.collect { match.group(it) }
 println test
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for Version Number Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37280527/regex-for-version-number-format)

Comment: no not the same